# Design custom UIView using XCode 4

Tags: xcode, uiview

This has been asked before, but I cannot find a definitive answer.

I would like to design a custom `UIView` class. I would like to do the layout in XCode 4 in a XIB file. Ideally:

- I have the files MyView.h, MyView.m and MyView.xib.
- The code defines the behavior and the XIB file defines the layout.
- The code may have outlets into the XIB file to reference the layout elements.
- The loader of the view could be different objects.

I'd like to be able to load the view by:

```
MyView *v = [MyView myView];
```

I've tried lots of different methods of setting the File's Owner and loading the XIB via NSBundle, but I keep getting key value coding problems.

Can anyone share the basic method to do this?

I have a [repo of my current code here](https://bitbucket.org/stasiana/myview). As you can see, it generates a key value coding error.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I seem to have figured it out.

Keys are the following:

- The XIB file UIView only needs to be a generic UIView. No need to set it to your subclass.
- The File's Owner needs to be your subclass.
- Outlets go to the File's Owner.

In your custom UIView, load the NIB as follows:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:nil];
        UIView *v = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] lastObject];            
        v.frame = self.frame;
        [self addSubview:v];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you instantiate it? In my "container" class I have an outlet for my custom view as a property, but when I try to do `self.customView = [[CustomView alloc] init];`

the view does not come on screen, even though I know that it's correctly initialized because I can see the NSLog()s I put in my custom view's initWithFrame: method.

From within my main view controller, BEFORE instatiating the new class, the view is as I've defined it in the storyboard: `<CustomView: 0x6a83bb0; frame = (38 153; 244 153); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a83c60>>`

However, inside the custom view's initWithFrame:, the frame is `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}` and the view is `<UIView: 0x68ca160; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x68d1800>>`.

After the initialization has taken place, the main view's property for the custom view is barely `(null)`, which baffles me.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple here. Are you even supposed to define the custom view's within the main view in the storyboard at all?

Thanks!